# How can I tell if Windows (PE) executables have debug symbols?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

Most of the executables I want to reverse are older executables, so it's possible for them to have embedded symbols, rather than having them in a pdb file.

I'm on Linux, so a tool that can run on Linux would be preferable.

Comment: Maybe [`dumpbin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) can help?

Comment: Your question asked how to tell if executables have debug symbols. Using DumpBin /headers (or any other PE parser) under Wine, look for a nonzero RVA and size values for "Debug Directory".  If so, you have debug symbols of some sort.  If you parse the Debug Directory, you can then find out if its an external PDB or if the debug info is embedded.  Interpreting the internal/external data is another matter.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a PE file of which you know that it has debug symbols? I doubt I've seen such a thing before

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Nearly every DLL distributed with Windows has split debug symbols which can be downloaded from the Microsoft Symbol Server (symsrv)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I know. That's why I'm asking to see a PE file with embedded symbols